Partially sync Google Calendars
In the current situation, I have two calendars, A and B. A is my private calendar under my own account. B is a shared company calendar under someone's account. Everyone puts their appointments in B. This gets cluttered very quickly, so I've been copying my own appointments into calendar A to get rid of the clutter.
At the moment, I am just double adding/editing/deleting events whenever I make a change to either calendar.
What I want the system to do is to add/edit/delete events in one calendar and have them automatically synced to the other. Either me changing something in A, or someone else changing my events in B. Luckily, the event names follow a standardized pattern, so it should be easy to separate mine from others with some light regex. The question now is how I get the two calendars to listen to each other.
